# What is the default Session Storage for Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have read the Spring Boot documentation and I got knowledge about Spring Session from [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-session.html) document.

But I see that **HttpSession** class works without adding any dependencies in my code.

- JDBC
- Redis
- Hazelcast
- MongoDB

So...

I'm guessing that Spring Boot provides Session Storage by default. Does anyone know about this? I looked at spring docs but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to you run your app? Do you use Tomcat or Jetty embedded server or deploy it in those servers? They all have their own session storage implementation. Tomcat [uses](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/manager.html#Standard_Implementation) file-bases session storage by default.

Comment: Damn, I was wondering, how this is possible, that session lives even when I restart app. Now it's clear. BTW property server.servlet.session.persistent=false prevents that

Answer (score 1):

The session storage that you mentioned by default is provided by the Servlet container.It is just an internal `java.util.Map`.

Spring Session is a Spring sub-project. It is optional and its purpose is to allow you swap the session stroage mechanism provided by the container with the one provided by Spring Session  which can be RDBMS, Redis ,Hazelcast Cluster or MongoDB .`HttpSession` is then stored in the container agnostic way such that you can have session persistence /session clustering more easier. You no longer need to consult the Servlet container documentation for how to configure a cluster etc.

If you want to use Spring session, you still have to include the dependencies from the spring session project.